# Save playlist to desired location

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

The question is very simple:

I have a playlist

```
var playlist = new Windows.Media.Playlists.Playlist();
```

And I want to save this playlist to a folder of my choice (for example the desktop or D:\New Folder\Sub Folder). The thing is the `playlist.SaveAsAsync` method requires a class that implements Windows.Storage.IStorageFolder and I dont know how I can generate such a class which has the desired path as its root folder.

**EDIT** Using the **folder picker** seems to do the job for now, but is there any way I can get a Storage Folder through a **file picker**?

Answer (score 1):

I have solution in C#, you can easily convert it in JS. You need to use `FolderPicker` to pick your choice of location to save the playlist. You can save playlist in 3 formats.

- Windows Media (*.wpl)
- Zune (*.zpl)
- M3U (*.m3u)

See the below given code.

```
var playlist = new Playlist();

//audio1 to audio4 are the object of StorageFile class
playlist.Files.Add(audio1);
playlist.Files.Add(audio2);
playlist.Files.Add(audio3);
playlist.Files.Add(audio4);

/* Initialize folder picker. Music lib is suggested start location and I've added
storage file type filters. */

FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m3u");
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wpl");
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".zpl");
StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

/* Playlist.SaveAsAsync takes four argument. First is destination folder, second is
 playlist name, 3rd is file collision option and 4th is playlist format */

var file = await playlist.SaveAsAsync(folder, "myplaylist", NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName, PlaylistFormat.WindowsMedia);
```

[Playlist.SaveAsAsync method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768262.aspx)

[FolderPicker class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-2)

Comment: That is a legit workaround, but still I would like the user to be able to save a playlist normally (choosing the format and name in a file picker).

Comment: It's not workaround. `SaveAsAsync` offers just folder to pick, it **should** allow to save playlist according to user's choice of name as well as format.

Comment: You can create a popup like screen which allows user to select destination folder, then file name in text box and a combo box for playlist type. Then on button click save the playlist like user entered.